# Unused apache directory is indexable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

On my Joomla 3 site (in case that's relevant), the directory /manual/images is index-able, even though it doesn't exist (there is no /manual folder in my document root. The images that are linked to it are from apache (favicons, apache logo, etc).

[image]

I've gone through the apache conf and htaccess files and set "Options -Indexes", and I've also tried removing "Indexes" from the Options entirely, with no result.

I've also tried creating the /manual/images directory and putting a .htaccess file with a deny all, but that had no impact either.

Is there a way to remove this phantom apache directory, or make it non index-able?

Comment: What happens when you visit `http://domain.com/manual/images` in your browser?

Comment: I get the image that I posted in the question, that's a screenshot of it

Comment: Those are ALIASes to apache-specific directories that are set by default; if you want to modify or disable those, you would need access to the central server configuration.

Comment: I have access to that configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule as **very first rule** in your root .htaccess (just below `RewriteEngine On` line):

```
RewriteRule ^manual/images - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Adding this rewrite rule didn't resolve the problem, the index is still accessable

Comment: Did you check `httpd.conf` for any alias with `/manual/images`? Also try placing this rule `RewriteRule ^/?manual/images - [F,NC]` below `RewriteEngine On` line in `httpd.conf` and remember to bounce Apache.

Comment: I've checked the httpd.conf for anything that says "manual" or "manual/images" but its not in there. I'll try adding that rewrite rule there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Find /etc/apache2/conf-available/apache2-doc.conf and edit this lines like this:

```
#Alias /manual /usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/

#<Directory "/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/">
#    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
#    AllowOverride None
#    Require all granted
#    AddDefaultCharset off
#</Directory>
```